# How to track an text only email or a participant using text client?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-mail

I am implementing an custom email tracking system where in an HTML email I will embed an image, when the user loads the image a request is send to the server based on that the particular email will be tracked as read/open.

Question:
If this email is received by a person how is having an text only email client, then what can be done to track it?

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably nothing you can do, since text only emails don't have any active/dynamic part that could be used for tracking.

Even the beacon (hidden image) is questionable, since most email programs don't load external content for exactly that reason.

This would allow spammers to validate their bulk mail is actually read.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't track the e-mail when the recipient doesn't allow the images to be loaded or has as text-only client which doesn't show the HTML at all.

Answer (score 0):

Social engineering – trick user to load image or click specially formed link.

Answer (score 0):

You could put unique links in the text version. You wouldn't be able to track opens, but you could track text-only click rates, thus getting an idea of text vs HTML engagement numbers.

I cannot find any stats on text-only open rates. I'm just not aware that it's possible to track.